# automating windows based application running on thin client

Tags: selenium, user-interface, winappdriver, winium, thin-client

I need to automate a windows based application running on thin client. Im trying winapp driver with selenium for achiving this. but with inspect.exe I cant locate the elements.

if its not possible on thin client i have another question. with intellij i can automate eclipse. because i can locate elements in eclipse. but i cant locate elements in intellij. what is difference? why i cant locate elements in every windows based application?

if its not possible with selenium and winappdriver or with winium. what else can i use for automate the windows based application which running on thin client and not both.

Comment: Did you run inspect.exe with the same permissions as you did for intellij?
Also, having accessibility is app dependent, thus controls will only be accessible if the developers who build that app implemented it. So make sure you test the scripting tools on the same app.
If the screen resolution stays the same every time the script gets executed, you could use screen coordinates instead of windows elements to execute your script.
In that case a point and click recorder will suffice.

Comment: thank you for your reply. yes they are in same permission. Okay it probably about application then. I will try with coordinates then but the automation purpose in here is more testing. can i do assertion with coordinated automation?

Comment: In case of testing, simple clicking coordinates won't be enough, because you don't actually read any data from your screen that way.
What OS are you running on those thin clients? I'm running Microsoft Visual studio Coded UI tests on a Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry pro OS without any problems. Try and see if inspect.exe works on a windows app like calculator, that one is popular in many automation examples.